# How can the user work on other things while VBA code is running in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way so that the user can work on other things while VBA code is running in Excel?  I have a program that creates printouts with questions and the user, at times, will need over 100 printouts with different questions on each and that can take a while.  If the user ever tries to switch to some other program, such as PowerPoint or Outlook, the code pops up with an Exception Error.  This does not cause the code to crash or anything and it properly runs after the user returns to Excel and hits the "Ok" button.  So is there some sort of code I can add so when it is running, the code ignores what the user is doing and just runs with no exception error?

Comment: `Application.DisplayAlerts = False`

Comment: Thank you for the thought, but that did not solve the problem.